# ui-router - ui view and link not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying out ui-router for angular. I added this line of code to my app module in my app.js:

```
angular
 .module("ngClassifieds", ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router'])
 .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider){

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('teal')
        .accentPalette('orange');

    $stateProvider
        .state('stateone', {
            url:'/stateone',
            template: '<h1>State one</h1>'
        })
        .state('statetwo', {
            url: '/statetwo',
            template: '<h1>State two</h1>'
        });

});
```

On my html I just put an empty ui-view to test whether or not i'm getting those two headers but with no luck:

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Testing it out on my localhost link by putting in:

```
localhost:8080/#/stateone
localhost:8080/#/statetwo
```

But for some reasons it's not loading/showing any of the headers on any of those links but just showing my page without the headers.

I have already included angular-ui-router.js into my index.html

If anyone could point out what I did wrong, that would great.

In case anyone is wondering : this is the order of my scripts:

```
  <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

 <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

 <script src="components/classifieds.ctr.js"></script>
 <script src="components/classifieds.fac.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the order of scripts on your index.html correct? Also, do any errors show up in the console?

Comment: @AyushBahuguna there's no error in the console. When I ran the link localhost:8080/#/stateone - it would change to this : http://localhost:8080/#!#%2Fstateone and the page would show up without the header. Same goes to the statetwo link

Comment: You 're using ui-sref as anchord tag?

Comment: @digit it isn't necessary. he is explicitly entering the url.

Comment: @rory-h could you put your code on plunker? That would help us understand better. put all the files and everything that you currently have.

Comment: Yeh @AyushBahuguna is right..its difficult to figure out what actually went wrong .. U can anyways have a look at my answer

Comment: @AyushBahuguna here's my code on plunker, but had difficulty pasting it on there. this is the best I could do: https://plnkr.co/edit/hbOPVkU6kH9ZInbABm1i?p=preview

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is: When I go to localhost:8080/#/stateone - it will show my page with the header Stateone, when I go to localhost:8080/#/statetwo - it will show my page together with the State Two header

Comment: every single time I put in this link : localhost:8080/#/stateone or two. it renders my link to this : http://localhost:8080/#!#%2FFstateone  and no errors in the console and the header on each link is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not get any error it is difficult to understand what went wrong but you can have a look at my plunkr and figure it out. I removed angular-material.

https://plnkr.co/edit/WGjzY6flSx5Ces1moSPk?p=preview

```
    <script>
    angular
 .module("ngClassifieds", ['ui.router'])
 .config(function( $stateProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('stateone', {
            url:'/stateone',
            template: '<h1>State one</h1>'
        })
        .state('statetwo', {
            url: '/statetwo',
            template: '<h1>State two</h1>'
        });

});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <a href="#/stateone">Link1</a>
     <a href="#/statetwo">Link2</a>
     <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to use '#/' in href